# strange string variable behavior

Tags: asp.net

I have the following keys stored in web.config file

```
<appSettings>
       <add key="AdminReqEditURL" value="http://portal.joshworld.local/SitePages/EditRequisition.aspx?RID="/>
    <add key="ITReqEditURL" value="http://portal.joshworld.local/Services/IT/SitePages/EditITRequisition.aspx?RID=" />
</appSettings>
```

In my code behind I have a function like the following from where I am reading key values and returning as a string from function.

```
public string getURL(string pReqID, int pReqType)
{
    String ForAdmin = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdminReqEditURL"].ToString();
    String ForIT = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ITReqEditURL"].ToString();

    if (pReqType == 1)
    {
        string theURL = ForAdmin;
        theURL = theURL + pReqID;
        return theURL;
    }
    else
    {
        string theURL = ForIT;
        theURL = theURL + pReqID;
        return theURL;
    }
}
```

**When I call reqid  for example 5429 with type 1 it returns**

```
"http://portal.joshworld.local/SitePages/EditRequisition.aspx?RID=5429"
```

**But when I call reqid for example 5429 with type other then 1 like 0 or 3 or 4 it returns**

```
"http://portal.joshworld.local/Services/IT/SitePages/EditITRequisition.aspx?RID=54" +
    "29"
```

I've tried reducing the length of second url and it works fine but as soon as I increase the length it returns string in strange manner. How to rectify this.

Comment: How do you mean it returns it in this strange format? Where do you see that?

Comment: the function is a part of my WCF based webservice..and I am using WCFTestclient ..why in the second case its showing two strings instead of showing as one.

Comment: If you debug through `getUrl` and look at the value of `theUrl` before it is returned, you will see a single string. What you are seeing is happening elsewhere.

Comment: A string variable can't contain two string instances. I believe that it's shown that way in your test tool just because the string is longer.

Comment: oh gosh..yeah it is indeed a problem of WCFTestClient as I tested the same in my .net application and it showed the string the way I wanted. thanks